# Plot peak shift from LED spectrum

Tags: python, shift, maxima, spectrum

I'm working on a code to track a shift in spectrum of an LED over 100 scans. I import my data as an ASCI file. Using the find_peaks function I can print the peak position for the first scan. My end goal is to plot the peak position vs scan number.
Hopefully someone can help, I'm fairly new to python.

````
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, height=14e4)

spec=LED[peaks[0], 0:]
spec=spec / spec[0]
scans=np.arange(0,101)

plt.plot(scans, spec, 'b-')
plt.xlabel('scans')
plt.ylabel('Peak shift')
plt.show() ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a detailed description of the problem you're having. Does the above code give an error? If it fails to do what you want, please describe how it fails and what the desired result is.

Comment: The code doesn't give an error but it returns a plot of the changing intensity (y-axis) of the peak while I am looking to plot the change in the x position